# How to backup programs without using apt cache?

Tags: installation, apt, package-management, backup

Is there any way to backup installed software, install a fresh Ubuntu system, and restore the software on the newly installed system, without an Internet connection? I already cleared my apt cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Backup**

1. Ctrl + Alt + T(Opens Terminal)
2. Get root access (i) Type "sudo su" then press Enter (ii)Give Your Password
3. Install Require Packages (i)apt-get install fakeroot(ii)apt-get install dpkg-repack
4. cd to Your Backup directory For example ,Say U have a Thumbdrive and created a folder backup "cd /media/usb/backup"
5. Run the Following in terminal

   fakeroot -u dpkg-repack `dpkg --get-selections | grep install | cut -f1`

**.Restore**

Steps to reinstall packages

1.<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>T</kbd>(Opens Terminal)

2.cd to the "backup" directory

Eg: "cd /media/usb/backup"

3.Run the Following in terminal

`sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

Source :[Facebook doc](https://www.facebook.com/groups/231993340233769/doc/237402699692833/)

**Edit**

If it lead to broken dependencies open the terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: feel free to edit

Answer (score 1):

You can use dpkg :
    sudo dpkg --get-selections > backup

and then you copy backup, and then you reinstall and use

```
sudo dpkg --set-selections < selections
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -u dselect-upgrade
```

( not from me, found on http://syslog.tv/2010/07/02/using-dpkg-selections-to-backup-and-install-packages/ )

However, you need to have the same sources.list ( especially if you used ppa ), so I recommend to make a copy of /etc/apt/. If you plan to upgrade the Ubuntu version, not all versions would be identical, so maybe that's not exactly what you want

Answer (score 1):

This one-liner will tar up all the (official) files of your installed packages:

```
dpkg -l | grep ^ii | awk '{print $2}' | while read pkgname; do dpkg -L $pkgname; done | while read fname; do test -f "$fname" && echo $fname; done | tar zcf /path/to/backup.tar.gz -T-
```

Answer (score -1):

Install and use 'aptoncd'

This will take whatever you have in /var/cache/apt/archives and create a media (CD-DVD) to use to install software via apt. You can the upgrade and install the same set of softwares in several machines with no need to re-download those packages again.

Comment: -1 ,because aptoncd uses apt cache