# Ubuntu installation disk with updates included

Tags: installation, updates

I would like to install Ubuntu on a computer but I don't want, right after the installation, to go through the process of installing the updates which came out since the release of the latest Ubuntu version.

I know there is an option to install the updates *during* the installation, but I can't use that because the computer I want to install Ubuntu onto doesn't have direct access to Internet. I would like the latest updates to be included in the installation disk.

Where can I find an Ubuntu installation disk with updates included?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge you would need to wait for point release - one is due in August which will have updates included.

I've successfuly copied the cache from one machine to another, there are other ways of dealing with it though.

[How to backup programs without using apt cache?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143642/how-to-backup-programs-without-using-apt-cache)

Answer (score 1):

Since the updates are released frequently by canonical/ubuntu, Instead of searching for the distro with updates included, you should prefer getting them on the official releases. 
 So as an alternative, I can suggest you one thing: (How to get updates for machines not connected to internet)

1. (You need internet for this step) First time check for updates using update manager. It would download something like 20 MBs. 
   You can do this by running this:

   sudo apt-get update
2. Now run the following command. 
   `sudo apt-get --print-uris --yes upgrade | grep ^\' | cut -d\' -f2 > ~/updatesjune05` 
   It will create a file called updatesjune05 in your home directory with the links to download from.
3. Now carry this file with you to a machine with internet connection( with an OS- windows linux whatever).
4. Use another software to download the files listed there. 
   **On windows:** You can use a third party software say orbitdownloader (a freeware) and tell it to import the list from the file you created earlier. 
   **On linux:** you can use wget -i /patheto/thefileyoucreated.
5. After the files are downloaded, carry them to the first machine with no internet. Run the following command.
   sudo cp -r /pathwhereyourdownloadedfilesare/* /var/cache/apt/archives/
6. Run sudo apt-get upgrade 
   The updates should install without any trouble.

Comment: This would create a backup file of the updates of a specific machine, not a general one of all the default packages included in the installation. Anyway, it seems it doesn't work as that command `sudo apt-get ... updatesjune05` generates an empty file.

Comment: The command works after completion of first step. i.e. First time you need to run sudo apt-get update. It needs internet as mentioned in first step.